# How we should handle development questions?

Tags: discussion

Stated from the proposal:

> Q&A site for researchers, **developers**, and users of Tor

But in which way we should handle questions about the development? I'm thinking more of serious problems with the code, which are not directly dedicated to Tor and more a generous problem. Should we move them to Stackoverflow?

In the other way, questions about the Tor code itself should be accepted, but how broad they are allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that deal with coding problems involving the Tor source code could be asked either on Stack Overflow or Tor.SE. Keep in mind, that there can and will be scope overlaps between Network sites and many questions can be on-topic/off-topic on different sites just based on how they get worded.

So, with that, I think :

- Questions which involve **writing and debugging code** involving the Tor source or of any of the related tools should be **on-topic** here. They will also be on-topic on Stack Overflow, which is entirely fine.
- Questions involving **understanding the Tor source** code and its logic or working should also be **on-topic** on the site.
- General algorithmic and debugging issues with *code which cannot be reasonably said to be specific to Tor* should be off-topic.

Comment: But what's about general coding problems (like errors with functions, loops and so stuff)?

Comment: @Pazi Covered in last point.

Comment: I like this approach, it will help ensure we don't become a bugreport site.